# Has anyone converted from using exports and require to a single file output for Typescript

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript

We started our TS project using the external modules with `require Foo = ('./Foo')` and while the organization of it is very useful, it requires then that you use requirejs(AMD moddules) or similar. While this isn't a problem I have noticed in doing perf analysis that this ends up with our page making a large number of requests for JS files. We have a reasonably complex app with a lot of smaller js files and that ends up with us making about 160 requests for various files. This obviously has a large overhead and mobile clients don't deal well with lots of requests. I am looking in to what it would take to move away from this pattern and use TypeScripts -out parameter to generate one file. I was curious if anyone had made a similar jump and had any advice for making this type of change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using external modules is correct. Switching to internal modules to reduce network requests is wrong and goes against best practices when writing future-proof, modular code. To reduce the number of files loaded for a production application you simply need to add an AMD optimizer to your build process. If you are using RequireJS as your loader then your easiest path forward is to [use r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for optimizing your AMD modules into layers.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly emit all your source into one script.  The source code for TypeScript itself is split across a number of input source files that all emit into the one output file.  They all extend the same top level module ("TypeScript") also, as modules are open ended and you can continue adding to them.

One key thing a module system such as AMD gives you is a dependency management, so you can ensure the module you depend on are loaded and initialized before you need to use them (ignoring circular dependencies for the moment).  If you just emit code into one output script top to bottom without a module system, then you'll need to ensure the ordering of any code that runs at load time is correct.

So your options would seem to be either move to using internal modules and the --out parameter to get one large script with no dependency on a module loader (such as AMD or NodeJS) and ensure there are no ordering issues as load time, or as C. Snover alludes to, use the RequireJS optimizer to merge all your AMD modules into one script.  The second is probably easier if you already have your code written as RequireJS modules.

Answer (score 2):

**What didn't work for us**

When we developed a mid-sized project that eventually had to result into one js file, we used the AMD/requirejs approach. The project consisted of 13 `ts` modules, each in a separate file. Dependencies were imported using `import` and the modules were `export`ed. We generated separate js files from the ts files (tsc --module amd), so we were able to unit test the individual modules. Deployment was done using requirejs and grunt by concatenating the 13 files into one, stripping the `defines` and adding and header (containing the UMD) and footer file. This approach is followed by jQuery as well. However, we ran into the problem because we did not us a global object to which all the individual modules were attached. As a result, code in one module did not know of other modules.

We could have solved this probable by introducing a global object and attach all modules to it.

**What did work us**

However, we tried another approach. Typescript's tsc compiler option `--out` does not only concatenates all ts files into one js file, but it takes all dependencies into account (as you might expect). So there is no need for requirejs anymore. External modules are loading using the

`/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>`

Using grunt-contrib-concat we then prepend an UMD header and append a closing footer and that's it.

I'm sure there are more solutions, but this one worked for us.